# align columns in a row on text end using bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-5

using Bootstrap 5 I want to display a div and a canvas on on a row till `md` as a Breakpoint

I want to alling the canvas right after the text ends
at the moment each part has a equal width

How can I remove the unused space from the div ?

[image: canvas alignment]

```html
<link
      href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      rel="stylesheet"
      integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />


 <section class="p-5">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row g-4 bg-primary">
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <div>
              <p>
                first stuff
                <span>hi</span>
              </p>
              <p>
                second stuff
                <span>hii</span>
              </p>
              <p>
                third stuff
                <span>hiii</span>
              </p>
              <p>global stuff <span>hello</span></p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-6 bg-dark">
            <canvas></canvas>
          </div>

          
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to change the size written after md of colon property of both the classes  and . I am also providing the code below:

```
<html>
<head>
<!--<meta name="viewport" content="with=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">-->
<title>Header</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />

<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" />
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?
family=Montserrat:wght@300;500;700&display=swap rel="stylesheet">
<link
  href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
  rel="stylesheet"
  integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC"
  crossorigin="anonymous"
/>
</head>
<body>
<section class="p-5">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row g-3 bg-primary">
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <div>
          <p>
            first stuff
            <span>hi</span>
          </p>
          <p>
            second stuff
            <span>hii</span>
          </p>
          <p>
            third stuff
            <span>hiii</span>
          </p>
          <p>global stuff <span>hello</span></p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-9 bg-dark">
        <canvas></canvas>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace  Class `col-md-6` to `<div class="col-md-auto">` & `<div class="col bg-dark">`

```html
<link
      href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      rel="stylesheet"
      integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />


 <section class="p-5">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row g-4 bg-primary">
          <div class="col-md-auto">
            <div>
              <p>
                first stuff
                <span>hi</span>
              </p>
              <p>
                second stuff
                <span>hii</span>
              </p>
              <p>
                third stuff
                <span>hiii</span>
              </p>
              <p>global stuff <span>hello</span></p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col bg-dark">
            <canvas></canvas>
          </div>

          
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
```